# Map device driver code to Logic Analyzer waveform

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, waveform

As per SDIO specification, the sequence of operations (for write transaction) take place as:

Command53 -- CommandLatency -- Command53Response -- ResponseLatency -- startbit -- write-number-of-bytes -- CRC -- endbit -- WriteLatency -- startbit -- CRC -- endbit -- busybit.

During benchmarking of SDIO UART driver, the time values which I got were more than expected. A lot of latency was found especially during write transaction.

Reasons for latency could be scheduler allocating processor time to other processes, delay in work queues, etc.

I would like to analyze and understand the latency. May be understanding the mapping between the device driver code and the Logic Analyzer waveform can lead to some cue.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Thank you.

---

EDIT 1: 
Sorry! I assumed a few things.

In [sdio_uart_transmit_chars()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mmc/card/sdio_uart.c?v=2.6.32#L443) there is a call to `sdio_out()` which in turn calls [sdio_writeb()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mmc/core/sdio_io.c?v=2.6.32#L391) and this call writes byte wise (one byte at a time) to a SDIO UART device.  I modified the driver to use [sdio_writesb()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mmc/core/sdio_io.c?v=2.6.32#L464) i.e. multi-byte mode. This  reduced the time taken to write X bytes relatively. Interestingly, with increase in size of  write data, there was exponential increase in WriteLatency (as mentioned above).

This latency could be because of many reasons. I would like to understand these reasons.

Setup: I am using Linux (v 2.6.32) laptop and a loadable kernel module (which is modified [sdio_uart.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mmc/card/sdio_uart.c?v=2.6.32))

---

EDIT 2:

May be adding 'SDIO' in this question is misleading..(not sure at the moment). The reasons for delay could be generic to any device driver while interacting with the hardware and it may be independent of SDIO write process.

If somebody can point me to related online resource, I would be happy to explore and update  the result here.

Hope I added more clarity this time. Please comment if I the question is still not clear.

Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT 3:

Yes, I am looking at the signals on Logic Analyzer (LA) and there are longer delays during and between writes than I expected.
To give an idea about time values:
For 512 bytes transfer: At the hardware level theoretically the write should take 50 micro seconds (us), however in reality I got 200 us.

This gap of 150 us is what I want to understand.

Note:
1) I am rounding off the time values to simplify the case.
2) All the time values are calculated at Kernel level and no user space issue is involved here.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.  Also please describe the hardware and connections in your setup.

Comment: Are you saying that you are looking at the signals on the logic analyzer and there are longer delays between events than you expect? What times are you seeing and what times are you expecting? Where in the transactions are you seeing the delays?

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Hope I have added enough details over my 3 edits so far.

Comment: @JayM: Please refer the updated question for more details. Thank you all for your time again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing worth looking at is if your sd interface functions by DMA, such that the driver can program the state machine and then it just runs by itself, or if getting the message out requires repetitive service by the driver, which might be delayed by other kernel obligations.

You could also see if there may be an I/O bottleneck, for example is the SD interface or whatever bus it hangs off of also used for something else?

Finally you could search for ways to increase the priority.  At an extreme, you could switch to a real time SD driver rather than a normal one.

Comment: This is Linux kernel 2.6.32's SDIO interface, which I don't think uses DMA. Yes, I/O bottleneck is something I am studying at present, thank you for pointing out. Changing the priority is not an option available in my situation. The main intention here is to understand the delays/latencies in the current setup without tweaking any of its parameters. Once the reason/s is/are known then probably a decision about setup optimization would be appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend you get the programmers manual for the involved hardware engine itself and investigate what making the hardware click requires; then you can tell how close to the optimum the current driver is.

Comment: I/O bottleneck along with CPU context switching may be the two possible reasons. Thank you all for your suggestions, comments and time.

Comment: Straton, to clarify earlier observation: "2.6.32's SDIO interface doesn't use DMA". It does use DMA! It uses scatter-gather (sg) APIs to do the data transfer. Ultimately the SDIO driver uses sg_init_one() [http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/scatterlist.c?a=blackfin#L106].